# Installing a Java Jar file on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java, packages, jar

Is there a way to package a jar file (for example, a .deb) and install it on Ubuntu 11.10. Basically I want to automate the installation of Jar file when I create a Ubuntu VM (using KVM).

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot *install* jar files, do you mean to run them ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot package/install a .jar file.

Java requires the Java Runtime Environment to run programs. You must have that installed on the client in order to run a .jar (Java executable) file.

Install the Java Runtime Environment on your client, copy the .jar, and run `java -jar /path/to/file.jar`.